# incomprehensible behavior (changing the width) of the <input /> element in the bootstrap <Card>

Tags: css, input, bootstrap-4, flexbox, react-bootstrap

I use React with Bootstrap (but it does not matter what React).

I had to make a card (element `<Card>`) with a range of two dates, which can be set with 2 elements `<input />`.

That is, the field should look like this:

```
from <input /> to <input />
```

In this case, the elements<input > must be the same size and the entire field width with `<Card>`.

I decided to do it through flex (I guess you can do it with bootstrap classes too, but I just started studying it), I got the code (without `<input />` yet):

```
<div className="element-datepicker">
    <div className="i1">from</div>
    <div className="i2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div className="i3">to</div>
    <div className="i4">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

it turned out to be such an object, which is wonderful, because it was designed (colors are needed for positioning visualization).

[image]

Here is the css code:

```
.ipc-element-datepicker {
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;

    width:                  100%;
    height:                 100%;

    display:                flex;
    flex-direction:         row;
    justify-content:        space-between;
    align-items:            center;

    box-sizing:             border-box;
}

.element-datepicker .i1, 
.element-datepicker .i2, 
.element-datepicker .i3, 
.element-datepicker .i4 {
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;
}

.element-datepicker .i1 {
    padding-right:          0.35rem;
    background:             orange;
}
.element-datepicker .i3 {
    padding:                0 0.35rem;
    background:             limegreen;
} 
.element-datepicker .i2,
.element-datepicker .i4 {
    height:                 100%;

    flex-grow:              1;

    background:             red;
}
```

However, when I add `<input />` elements inside the i2 and i4 fields:

```
<div className="element-datepicker">
    <div className="i1">from</div>
    <div className="i2">
      <input type='test' name='date-s' />
    </div>
    <div className="i3">to</div>
    <div className="i4">
      <input type='test' name='date-f' />
    </div>
</div>
```

then the width of the card increases dramatically and I can't understand why this happens and how to fight it.

[image]

it turns out to be an object with a wider width than it was conceived

Here is the css code for `<input />`

```
.element-datepicker input {
    display:                inline-block;
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;

    width:                  100%;
    height:                 50%;

    border:                 1px solid black;
}
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem - it is necessary that the `<Card>` width does not change if I add `<input>` elements.

Comment: You say that the card width increases, but how wide should it be, according to the requirements?

Comment: @Dimitar Spassov, I wonder why the width increased at all when an element `input` was placed in the card. Why did this not happen when the `Dropdown` element was placed? In general, the size of column with cards was set as `xs={1.5}`.

Comment: I don't think there are decimal column options in Bootstrap, you can try to make it `xs={1}` or `xs={2}`, which will apply the correct classes and will also add `max-width` to the columns.